# Recreate a books TOC with HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: css, html, tableofcontents

**Solution Requirements**

**1st Requirement**
Must create indented ordered nested list items three levels deep to produce results that looks like
1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3.1 (instead of just 1, 2, 3, ...)

**2nd Requirement**
Long list items must wrap at the end of the line and keep indent for that level.

**3rd Requirement**
After list item display dots to end of line where page link is.

***Example of required result***

1. Lorem ipsum justo id. Neque elit platea volutpat velit dui ac, commodo class, libero pellentesque quisque massa tristique.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . .  .  .  . 1
2. Dolor sit ame.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   2
   2.1. Pharetra sodales varius mauris.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ..  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 5
   2.2. Nec commodo eu in duis. Erat adipiscing egestas porttitor aliquam consequat. Feugiat eget
           molestie.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .. 8
    
          
   2.2.1 Nunc non pede orem metus, ac eum diam. Imperdiet morbi eu in amet, sed wisi ut                 vestibulum in nam, nec quisque.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  ..  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .10
    
   2.3. Metus curabitur tristique.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  12
3. Vitae placerat.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .17

The following fiddle meets requirement 1 & 2  for solution requirements, but I'm strugling with working  solution to add 3rd requirement for leader dots. Any solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/digiron/bhr3pvc1/1/

CSS

```
/* Ordered List nested numbering */
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }

/* Ordered List nested indent */
ol > li {    
    display: table;
}

ol > li::before {    
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 0.5em;   
}
```

Comment: **SO Requirement:** You show something you have _tried_ to solve this yourself …

Answer (score 0):

You can mix `:after` and `before` on `li` tags to have both bullets (`content: "\2022";`) and counters

[Edit of your first fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3rtLw7q/12/)

Another snippet with custom counter and bullet :

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0d8x8c5/5/)

**HTML :**

```
<ul>
    <li>banana</li>
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
</ul>
```

**JS :**

```
ul
{
    counter-reset: list-counter;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li
{
    counter-increment: list-counter;
}

ul li:before
{
    content: counter(list-counter) " \2022  ";
}

ul li:nth-child(1):before
{
    color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2):before
{
    color: green;
}

ul li:nth-child(3):before
{
        color: blue;
}
```